I cheated through every single Calculus and Physics exams during my freshman year in pandemic. I ruined my life, I comitted a crime?
As the title says, I started college during the COVID pandemic and went for Software Engineering. I tried to study by myself but my country was a disaster around that time, so teachers at best tried to give lectures vía WhatsApp, but most of the time they just gave us a pdf.
I tried to study by myself, but I ruined everything at my first Calculus exam and I started to freak out. My family then got me in touch with my uncle who helped me studying. But then, he offered to help me during my exams. My 17-year old self with a an underdeveloped sense of ethics saw this as the best thing in the world. I passed Calculus 1 with his help.
Then in the next quarter I had to take Calculus 2 and Physics 1. My uncle helped on the first exam, but then he said he couldn't do it anymore. I tried to do it by myself but failed two exams on both subjects. So despair led me to reach my lowest point as a person, and I got a private tutor who would help me cheat to pass those subjects. In summary, I paid someone to help me cheat.
I did the same for Calculus 3 & 4, and for Physics 2. I got caught once, got a zero on an exam and I got to know the concept of academic fraud. I couldn't believe I had become a criminal.
I don't know what to do, the career became just coding so I haven't used anything related to math or physics. Nonetheless, guilt is eating me up. I know it was wrong; I know those were horrible actions. I just want to know how I can fix this, My family is aware of my behavior. I feel like I transformed us into criminals.

There doesn’t seem to be an academic problem here. The way you seem to be beating yourself up over something you cannot change anymore is not healthy, though - you might want to consider seeing a psychologist or life coach for this.

@MisterMiyagi Maybe not, but how often do we see "I cheated and got caught. How can I avoid the consequences?" questions? Seeing "I cheated and got away with it. How can I take responsibility for my actions?" is an refreshing change, and deserving of advice, even if not perfectly on topic. And since the consequences will largely come from academia, the people here are probably the most qualified to give it.

It isn't clear what you mean by "fix it". It also isn't clear why you talk of yourself as being a "criminal". Whether or not you are a criminal is a matter of law in the country where you committed the relevant behaviour. Whether or not you did something immoral is a matter of personal ethics interacting with cultural norms.
One can't undo one's life no matter that many people wish they could. You are then really faced with two different problems. First, your apparent feelings of guilt; second, the question of the extent to which your previous behavior will haunt the rest of your existence.
As to the first problem, people have all sorts of ways of dealing with guilt. They are worth reading about. Without limitation, they include:

simply endeavoring to lead a better life in the future
self forgiveness
religious rituals of penance and forgiveness
public restitution
confession, either to a single trusted individual who you feel has some special power to forgive you, or public confession which (a) might wreck your life even more, (b) not wreck your life and win public approval ... who knows which.

As for the second problem, sometimes there are no easy solutions to problems. Sometimes even minor infractions of a moral code end up having wide ranging negative effects on people's lives; consider for example, the people who have been publicly shamed for behaviors that are far from earth-shattering. On the other hand, as events over the last decade have shown, sometimes even serious cheating, fraud and dishonesty are rewarded beyond measure.
My suggestions: deal with your feelings of guilt first. Guilt is highly destructive. Consider what advice you would give to a friend who had behaved in the way you behaved? Consider whose forgiveness you really want or need. If it is from your family, have a conversation with them about what punishment they would want for you ... not so that you can do exactly what they say, but because you might discover that the punishment that they think is fitting is actually much less than you might think.

"Whether or not you did something immoral is a matter of personal ethics interacting with cultural norms." No. Cheating on exams is a good counterexample, as OP acknowledges.

"Guilt is highly destructive" - not true as a blanket statement. Guilt is a mechanism to self-regulate violations against norms. Only in overdrive it is self-destructive. It is actually useful to guide the person into just and righteous behaviour. Now OP was 17 when they committed academic sustained academic fraud. While bad, OP was still a juvenile or even a child when that happened. There is a reason for considering people children/juveniles, namely a certain element of immaturity. It does not make the act better, but...

...but it lets us evaluate the offender in a light that puts things to some extent in perspective. I am missing from this response the one thing that above "cry for help" asks for: how to make things better. Because it's not about the guilt, but about changing the acts in the future. Committing to never ever cheating again. Committing to respect the rules of academia. The first step to forgiveness or self-forgiveness is the decision to simply not repeat what caused one to feel guilt. Cheating is very bad in academia, but veers into criminal probably only when one outright fakes a degree.

So, whatever OP decides, the #1 step to fix things is: don't do it again and commit to never doing it again or help others to cheat. Whether OP goes for public self-punishment or confesses to a trusted friend or person of spiritual comfort, or whether they take it with them, is OP's decision. The second most important thing that would help is to endeavour to study honestly now, even for themselves and achieve the level that would have entitled OP to pass the exams the first time. These two things will help transform OP's feeling of guilt into something productive for them and others.

Yes, I know that being a criminal depends on the laws of every country, As far as I know in UK, Canada, Australia, and some parts of the USA the kind of cheating I comitted could be prosecuted as fraud. But I haven't been able to find any chase that has been prosecuted in my country.
I comitted myself to never do it again, but the thought of getting expelled or me degree revoked comes once in a while to haunt me. The misconduct was serious
